# Can I disable a Vulnerability Scan rule for Azure SQL Managed Instance?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have a Azure SQL Managed instance with active vulnerability scan assessment routines. And everytime it gives me **VA2129 - Changes to signed modules should be authorized**. I have baselined it quite a number of times but this one has become recurring.

Is there any way to disable any vulnerability assessment rule like VA2129 for my managed instance to avoid baselining so many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in VA2129 rule that return not only the signed modules, therefore the rule failed although you put a baseline (this is becuse you Probably added more modules).
A fix for this rule will deploy in the next few weeks.

Currently you can't disable rule.

Comment: Hey That helps a lot, can you provide any official link where this has been mentioned just for my reference/reading.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more option, you can use the default disable rule mechanism of Microsoft Defender For Cloud to disable this rule - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/exempt-resource
In this case, you will not see the rule result in the portal

[How to disable the rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd63B.png)